# Targeting with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, fullpage.js

I am developing a website using the popular [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage) framework .

See my basic site: http://212.111.40.154/fullpage

**Problem**

The slider by default does not automatically scroll through slides, however the following working code does enable automatic scrolling on the slides BUT it applies scrolling to all sliders on the page.

There are two slides in the demo link above, so I need the top slider to scroll automatically but the second slider to not scroll automatically.

**Code**

How can this code be modified to only apply to one instance of slider.

```
// Automatic Slider
setInterval(function () {
    $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight();
}, 3000);
```

I'm sure others can benefit from your response, I will get `fullpage` author to add your answer to his FAQ.

Comment: The plugin is written in such a way that you can't do this without rewriting large portions of it. All the `$.fn.fullpage.xxx` methods gets all the sliders by a class the plugin adds to the inserted elements.

Comment: Hum, I thought this was the case, a tricky one the solve.

Answer (score 0):

Damn it was an easy one :(

**Solution:**

```
// Automatic Slider
setInterval(function () {
    $('#section0 .fp-controlArrow.fp-next').click();
}, 3000);
```